# Transactional test can't update/delete

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a `@Repository` that has a few different queries that update tables. These methods aren't annotated with `@Transactional` as the transactions are at the service level.

I would like to test these repositories. I've created a test class that is annotated with `@Transactional` but when the repository methods are called they fail with this:

```
Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

If I annotate each of the repositories methods with `@Transactional` it fixes the errors but I don't want to change the main code base. I should be able to have the transactions be created in the test.

I've created some example code to show the general structure I have.

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public class ExampleRepo extends JPARepository<X, Y> {

    // Adding @Transactional here fixes the test
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Example e set e.example=:example where e.id = :id")
    int exampleQuery(@Param("example") String example, @Param("id") int id);
}
```

**Test**

```
@Transactional
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootTest
public class RepoTest {
    
    private final ExampleRepo repository;

    @Autowired
    public RepoTest(final ExampleRepo repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    
    @Test
    void testExample() {
        // Fails
        repository.exampleQuery("example", 1);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

Shouldn't annotating the test as `@Transactional' fix this?

All the examples I can find use it. If I annotate each individual test with `@Transactional` it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you annotate your test class with `@SpringBootApplication`? It's not recommended! Anyway, it might be just for the rapid test. I don't know exactly what method do you want to test but for example for testing the save method below code is a good approach, try it and see it's working for you or not.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class RepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepo repository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void save_() {
        Object savedObj = repository.save(entity);
        assertNotNull(savedObj.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` as the project was split into multiple modules. There isn't a `@SpringBootApplication` defined in this project as it is only for the repositories/services.

Comment: I've tried writing this using `@Transactional` for the method but it still has the same error. Also if I try using `TestTransaction.start()` it says `Cannot start a new transaction without ending the existing transaction first`. So it appears there is a transaction.

Comment: To be JPA compliant you should use `javax.transaction.Transactional`, although in some versions combination of spring-data if `javax.transaction.Transactional` causes issues you can try using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

Comment: I'm using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. Sorry I should have copied in the imports.